# call public void method from Anonymous Windows in Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce1-app

How can i call **public void** method from **Anonymous Windows** in Salesforce for debugging purpose?

Like i have apex class:

```
public class student{
    {
        public void submit()
        {
            system.debug('This is student class');
        }
    }
```

---

and when i am executing this class using below syntax,

```
student s = new student();
system.debug(s.submit());
```

getting an error.

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void debug(void) from the type System

Comment: Can you edit your post to put at least the declaration of the method you want to call? (and if possible also the class)

Comment: You can call it exactly like you are saying. I guess then you are asking "how to make that call". If so, check the developer console / execute anonymous. (In Lightning: Setting wheel icon->Developer Console -> Debug --> Open execute anonymous window --> put code --> execute. then you can see the log under the logs tab)

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see the example of calling the apex class method from anywhere

**Sample Apex class**

```
public class student{
    public void submit(){
        system.debug('This is student class'); 
    }
    public static void staticFun(){
        System.debug('Hello');
    }
}
```

**Non-Static method**
create an instance of class then call

```
student objStudent = new student();
objStudent.submit(); // Output: This is student class
```

**Static Method**
You can call simply via class name

```
student.staticFun(); // Output: Hello
```

In Salesforce you can execute your test code or sample code in the anonymous window. To open an anonymous window follow these steps:

- Open Developer console after clicking on you name
- In developer console press ctrl+E to open anonymous window
- In an anonymous window, you can execute code whatever you want. In
  your scenario, you can create an instance of student class and call
  method.
- After writing code click execute in debug log you can see output.

In Lighting, you can open developer console via clicking on gear icon (setting icon).

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj. its resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Since your Student.submit() method already calls system.debug(), there's no need (nor possibility, since submit() returns void and system.debug() expects to receive a value to print) to call it again. Simply initiate the method that performs the debug internally, and you'll see the result in your debug log.

```
student s = new student();
s.submit();
```